# Fix mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE FROM keywords
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT keywords_relations.k_id FROM keywords_relations WHERE keywords.k_id = keywords_relations.k_id)
```

It is taking too long...I have 583,000 keywords (utf_unicode) and 1million keywords_relations. In past the query used to happen in 20-60 seconds, but I try running it now and it hasnt happened in half an hour.

Could you please suggest what might be wrong. Also, any other alterantives to this query.

I am trying to delete the keywords from the keywords table whose id dont exist in the keywords relations table.

Thanks

The site is http://domainsoutlook.com/

You can try and going on it and also see that all the queries are running slowly.

PS. The server crashed about a few days ago and a fsck check or something was carried out on the disk by my server maintenance support.

Indexes on keywords = k_id(primary), keywords(unique)
indexes on keywords_relations = k_id(index)

Comment: And what are the indexes on `keywords` and `keywords_relations`?

Comment: can you maybe show your table structures that are relevant for this?

Comment: Maybe someone could move this to dba.stackexchange

Comment: @eiefai: IMHO, this is a valid question for SO.

Comment: edited the question to include the indexes

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, I'm not saying it isn't valid, i just think we should start promoting dba.se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this instead and see if it makes a difference:

```
DELETE keywords
    FROM keywords
        LEFT JOIN keywords_relations
            ON keywords.k_id = keywords_relations.k_id
    WHERE keywords_relations.k_id IS NULL
```

Comment: how much difference is there between the one i am using and the one you have suggested.

Comment: @user381595: You should benchmark the two on your system and see what the difference is.

Comment: I would be tempted to benchmark the two only if the one I am already trying to do completed. I am running the one from you right now, and I would soon update you with the results.

Comment: It is saying sending data in the processes tab right now at 900 time elapsed

Comment: @user381595: You might want to see if running an `OPTIMIZE TABLE keywords, keywords_relations` improves things, especially if you've been doing a lot of these kinds of deletes.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE NOT EXISTS (subquery)` is known to cause performance issues in MySQL <5.4. Use `LEFT JOIN` instead

**WARNING**: Test it before running on live database. I claim no responsibility for data lost.

```
DELETE 
  k
FROM 
  keywords AS k
LEFT JOIN
  keywords_relations AS kr
USING (k_id)
WHERE
  kr.k_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you don't want to delete keywords, if there are one or more  `keyword_relations` belonging to it. So the first thing you could do is adding a `LIMIT 1` to your `SELECT`-Query.

You sure have set indexes for `k_id`, right? If yes, this actually shouldn't be a thing for MySQL...